Girl turns into a blue fairy or elf by popping her ears
From what I remember the book is about a girl around late teens - early 20s. I think she lives with one parent and one day she found out her other parent was a fairy or elf person. She either meets them or someone who is also the same type of creature and she goes with them I think maybe to save someone. The fairy or elf people can look normal but can change to their magic form which is just blue and maybe some facial changes as well. The main character learns to do this too by popping her ears. I know it was a series and I think that one of the books had a black cover with golden lips

By "popping her ears" do you mean something like the Toynbee maneuver or that they're popping out of her head?

Please don't replace tags that shouldn't be here.

And, just to clarify, [tag:fantasy-genre] is meant for questions about the genre, not to tag ID questions for fantasy books.

And [tag:elves] is for questions about elves, not questions that happen to mention them.

Don't add tags that don't belong. If you keep editing them back in we'll be forced to lock the question.
